# Removing white space between integers - JavaScript / ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, integer

I have a question . How can i remove white space between integers ? I want to keep my numbers as numbers and display them as one . I do not want to change my display to be a string .
The current result that is displayed into my table is something like : `1 004 123`
But on the end of the day i want to be : `1004123` . So how can achieve that ?
Again i do not want to use `myString.replace(/ /g,'')` , `str.trim()` or `toString()` , i want to keep them as numbers . Thank you .

Comment: Please share your existing code so we can get an idea of your implementation.

Comment: You can do some thing like this if only spaces are in between numbers: `Number(myString.split(" ").join(""))`

Comment: `("2 3 4").replaceAll(" ", "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to treat it as string, then you can parse it. e.g.

```
var stringNum = "1 004 123".toString().replace(/ /g,'');
var num = parseInt(stringNum);
console.log(num); //1004123
```

Comment: Okay , but it is my number that has to be converted to string not strung to string . So if i do `var stringNum = 1 004 123.toString().replace(/ /g, ``);` it is not working

Comment: "1 004 123" is a string already, why do we need to convert it to string again?

Comment: "1 004 123" is a string but it might be coming in your case as variable. Your piece of code is limited, so I gave you option, in case if you need to convert it to string as .replace(/ /g, ``) is expecting it to be string

Answer (score 0):

Double convert? From integer to string for deleting withe space and after from string to integer.
You can do this?